# Getting a CSS gallery to auto-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have this gallery on my index page and my client wants it to auto-scroll on a set timer. I have no clue how to do that since the code I'm using was borrowed from a friend.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
  src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
  src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


/* CSS reset */

dl,
dt,
dd,
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
fieldset,
input,
textarea,
p,
blockquote,
th,
td {
  margin: auto;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

fieldset,
img {
  border: 0;
}

address,
caption,
cite,
code,
dfn,
th,
var {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

caption,
th {
  text-align: left;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
}

abbr,
acronym {
  border: 0;
}

section,
header {
  display: block;
}


/* General Demo Style */

body {
  font-family: Cambria, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #3a2127;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}

.container1>header {
  padding: 20px 30px 10px 30px;
  margin: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

.container1>header h1 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.container1>header h1 span {
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000);
}

.container1>header h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
}


/* Header Style */

.codrops-top {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.codrops-top a {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

p.codrops-demos {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px;
}

p.codrops-demos a,
p.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
p.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 800;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #000;
}

p.codrops-demos a:hover {
  background: #000;
}

p.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
p.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <div id="Gallery">
    <div class="container1">
      <!-- Codrops top bar -->
      <!--/ Codrops top bar -->
      <section class="cr-container">

        <input id="select-img-1" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-1" checked/>
        <label for="select-img-1" class="cr-label-img-1">1</label>

        <input id="select-img-2" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-2" />
        <label for="select-img-2" class="cr-label-img-2">2</label>

        <input id="select-img-3" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-3" />
        <label for="select-img-3" class="cr-label-img-3">3</label>

        <input id="select-img-4" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-4" />
        <label for="select-img-4" class="cr-label-img-4">4</label>

        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="cr-bgimg">
          <div>
            <span>Slice 1 - Image 1</span>
            <span>Slice 1 - Image 2</span>
            <span>Slice 1 - Image 3</span>
            <span>Slice 1 - Image 4</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>Slice 2 - Image 1</span>
            <span>Slice 2 - Image 2</span>
            <span>Slice 2 - Image 3</span>
            <span>Slice 2 - Image 4</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>Slice 3 - Image 1</span>
            <span>Slice 3 - Image 2</span>
            <span>Slice 3 - Image 3</span>
            <span>Slice 3 - Image 4</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>Slice 4 - Image 1</span>
            <span>Slice 4 - Image 2</span>
            <span>Slice 4 - Image 3</span>
            <span>Slice 4 - Image 4</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cr-titles">
          <h3><span>Expierenced</span><span>Get that sound you're looking for from a Grammy nominated staff</span></h3>
          <h3><span>competitive</span><span>get more than a bang for your buck, get a rocket launcher</span></h3>
          <h3><span>Stacked</span><span>We have the tool for every job</span></h3>
          <h3><span>Comprehensive</span><span>We'll be with you from start to finish</span></h3>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: _“my client wants […] I have no clue how to do that, since the code I'm using was borrowed from a friend”_ – then I’d suggest you start working for clients only after you have a basic grasp of the technologies you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this fits what you want but is it like this you mean?

You will have to balance the time you acctually call the function, aswell as how much you will scroll the div every time.

```
var div = $('#img');
//How many milliseconds between each call. 
var time = 100;

setInterval(function(){
   var pos = div.scrollTop();
   //How far it will scroll everytime, 
   //increasing it will make it jump, and decreasing will make it more smooth.
   var scrollingsmoothness = 5;
   div.scrollTop(pos + scrollingsmoothness);
}, time)
```

Check the fiddle here!
 **Updated fiddle** to match your example, but with lots of more spans to show you the scrolling effect.
[Demo of autoscroll](http://jsfiddle.net/52jzM/1116/)